# I need some help calculating values for a variable 555 oscillator circuit

Tags: 555

For the past few hours i have been strugling with a 555 timer.

What i am trying to do is generate a square wave of variable frequency controlled by a potentiometer. At the time i have a 200KΩ potentiometer, and using [this page](http://www.ohmslawcalculator.com/555-astable-calculator) i calculated that if R1 is 200KΩ, then R2 has to be 10Ω, and the capacitor will be 1μf. 
That will allow me to vary the frequency between ~3Hz and ~120Hz which is just what i need.

After i built the circuit and placed an LED between pin 3 and ground (using the apropriate resistor), and connected the circuit to the 9V DC supply, the LED turned on but didn't blink to the slightest, so i thought it was some sort of high frequency, and thats why i couldnt see the oscilation, so i turned the potentiometer fully to the oposite side thus turning R1 to 200KΩ.
Still nothing, no oscilation at all! I even replaced the potentiometer with a fixed 200KΩ resistor just in case it was damaged but yet again, nothing.

The circuit is exactly as seen in the diagram of the page provided above, the only difference is that R2 between pins 6 and 7 is not of fixed value.

What have i done wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The 10ohms is the problem. This resistor determines the discharge time for the capacitor. The problem that you have is that this time is so fast that you will not see any change of state in the output. Try a much larger value (e.g. 33k with 200k R1) and see if your circuit works. You will still only see a very short flicker. For the frequencies that you are producing a speaker or oscilloscope would be better for detecting the oscillation.

Comment: Hello!
Thanks for your response, it is working atreat now!
The issue i have, is that when i soldered it on a PCB (previously it was on a breadboard) it does not blink again... -_-
The arangement is EXACTLY the same as on the breadboard with the exact same components.
The only thing i think may be is a missfire of the resetpin although it is connected directly to VCC :/ I dont know what to think... Any ideas?

Comment: some decoupling across the supply (e.g. 100nF capacitor) can help with "misfires".

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I added one, but no improvment at all. its worth mentioning that both circuits ran from the same supply, and one worked the other failed. The one soldered on a PCB seems to be movment sensitive/pressure sensitive. On certain angles and udner ceraint pressure it functions. Also when my finger comes in contact with the potentiometer, the entire thing stops (not because it moved)
My head is about to explode...

Comment: Dodgy pot or bad soldered joint!

Comment: Hello once more, 
Removed the pot, placed it on the breadboard and it is working flawlesly, as for the bad solder joints, i am not sure. Truth is that my soldering iron tip is... made of some kind of meltable material so it is now very rough and kind of destroyed but since yesterday i rebuilt the circuit on another part of the PCB with entirely new components and yet again it doesnt function... Do you need pictures of the circuits? 

Thank you, and sorry for all this back-and-forth thing :S

Comment: Also i replaced the pot with a fixed 200K resistor and still the same issue. So it may be a solder joint although i cant see anything to sugest that. 
By the way, could it be static damage to the chip?

Answer (score 1):

With your values it runs at 99.995% duty cycle, so LED looks like it's always on.

According to my calculations you need R1 - 10K, when R2 - 200K potentiometer and C - 1uF.
The duty cycle will be from 50% to 90%, so it would be visible.

[image: 555 timer]

Comment: Aha! I tried with a 47K resistor instead of a 10K (i didnt have one) and it worked so afterwards i made a 10K resistor with other paralel resistors. 

Thanks!